# Overriding user profile form

Tags: users, i18n-l10n, forms

So I have this function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form);
}
```

What I want to do is to remove "Language settings" fieldset with all the radio buttons inside it. But for some reason I don't have any array element which is responsible for displaying this data. I've read that this should be $form['locale'] but it's not there for sure. What migght cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Which modules are you using?

Comment: It could be that your form_alter happens before the locale field is added. Make sure your module runs last: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7

Comment: @David, glad it helped! I've added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that your form_alter happens before the locale field is added. Make sure your [module runs last](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).